# How to get the error in the approximation of the number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have this exercise:

> When performing the best approximation by excess to the hundredth of
>   the number
>   $-5,2672$ the error that is committed is

The error must be the absolute value of the substraction between the original number and the approximate number, that is:

$| -5.2672 - r|$, where $r$ is the approximate value, and is $-5.27$. That is a approximation by default, since the approximate value is less than the original.

So, the error must be $|-5.2672 +5.27 | = 0.0028$

Nevertheless, my answer is wrong and the correct answer must be $0.0072$

¿What is wrong in my development?, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the correct answer already hints at what the approach should be. Compare the correct answer to the number ($-5.2672$). What do you need to do to this number to obtain $0.0072$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for the best approximation by excess; you provide, as you correctly note, an approximation by default. Even though it is a closer approximation than the approximation by excess, it's not what the question asked you use as the approximate value. Instead, you need to use the best approximation by excess as the approximate value.

Comment: I used the approximation by excess, no by default. Since the in the $-5.2672$ the 7 is greather than $5$, so the number is $-5.27$

Comment: @Mattiu As you yourself pointed out in the question, "That is a approximation by default, since the approximate value is less than the original."

Comment: @Mattiu An approximation by excess must be greater than the original number. Your approximation was less than the original, so it as an approximation by default, not by excess.